# Screen real estate enlargment

Tags: display

I'd like more screen real estate on my 4K connected monitor, 

how can I get this done?

(You can do this on the mac display setting)

Comment: Please include which OS, your device information.

Comment: MPB late 2015, the newest version of EOs